# Can I use ASP.NET Web API in a Web Forms app on .NET 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, .net, json, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET web forms (not MVC) 4.0 app. I'd like to take advantage of Web API if possible. Specifically, I'm looking for the deep JSON integration, and not necessarily the resource-orientation (i.e. REST).

Am I better off using something else until I can fully migrate my app to ASP.NET MVC and 4.5?

Answer (score 2):

You can, read more about it here.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms